# How to stop a Script php running for ever?

Tags: php

I recently made the test to know if a `PHP` script will stop even if I disconnect. The answer was no, the script is still running and flooding my database. It's `while(true)` script, so do you guys know how to stop it from running?

It's not on a dedicated server that I have access... I only have the ftp, ssh , mysql access

I already tried to rename the name of the file that was executed, but it's still running

Comment: So you call the script from the command line or as a web page? In the latter case, the script will likely be killed after 30 seconds. For a command line script, you may have to kill the process yourself or reboot the server, if you have rights for any of that. Changing passwords or renaming the script isn't going to be of much use, since the script is already running (in memory) and is already connected to the database. You'll need some brute force.

Comment: How about restarting Apache?

Comment: To clarify, when a process is running, the source script no longer is connected to it (why the rename would not do anything).  I agree you may have to reboot your server, but it occurred to me you could rename the table in your database, thus creating an error in your script ... but that would be a terribly bad practice!  It would be far better to not write an infinite loop or test it on a server you control before releasing it to a server you can not control.

Comment: Let's start it twice, ... !

Comment: It finally got killed, I don't know how ...maybe by starting it twice

Answer (score 1):

Try to get list of all processes via ssh using

```
ps -ax
```

and find process of your script. If you find this process you can kill its with

```
kill %pid
```

where %pid is the process id from table of processes.